# Fitting a curve using Linear regression - CLS and NMF

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, model-fitting

I am trying to fit FTIR spectra with other reference spectra.
I have FTIR spectra of tissue and reference spectra of various components such as DNA, RNA and others. I want to fit the reference spectra into my input spectra. The size and shape of the input files are given as follows. I have performed CLS regression fitting and the fitting plot shows a good fit. However, I am doubtful about the log-liklihood and the BIC values. If any suggestions to improve the code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import io
from statistics import variance
import math

input_mat = io.loadmat('[path to input mat file]')
input_spectra = input_mat['ab'].T
input_wavenumbers = np.linspace(1800, 900, input_spectra.shape[1])

ref_spectra_mat = io.loadmat('path to reference spectra mat file')
reference_spectra = ref_spectra_mat['AB'].T
wavenumber_mat = io.loadmat('path to wavenummber mat file')
reference_wavenumbers = wavenumber_mat['wavenumber'][0]
reference_df = pd.DataFrame(reference_spectra, columns=reference_wavenumbers)
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_spectra, columns=input_wavenumbers)
matched_columns = {iw: reference_wavenumbers[np.argmin(np.abs(reference_wavenumbers - iw))] for iw in input_wavenumbers}
matched_reference_df = reference_df[list(matched_columns.values())]
matched_input_df = input_df.rename(columns=matched_columns)
print(f"Matched wavenumbers (input to reference): {matched_columns}")
matched_reference_df = matched_reference_df[matched_input_df.columns]
print(matched_reference_df)

X = matched_reference_df.to_numpy()
Y = matched_input_df.to_numpy()
coefficients = np.zeros((Y.shape[0], X.shape[0]))
for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
    coefs, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(X.T, Y[i, :], rcond=None)
    coefficients[i, :] = coefs
print("Coefficients shape:", coefficients.shape)

residuals = Y - reconstructed_spectra
se = residuals**2
n = Y.shape[1]
log_likelihood = []
for i in range(0,se.shape[0]):
  var = variance(residuals[i,:])
  ll = log(np.cumprod((np.sqrt(2*np.pi*var[i,:]))^(-1)*np.exp(-se[i,:]/(2*var[i,:]))))
  log_likelihood.append(ll)
print("Log Likelihood:", log_likelihood)
```

I need suggestions on logliklihood calculations.
I get either very high value of 7 or 8 digits or error due to underflow

ANy quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very easy to dissect, please repost or edit to make it more focused